# Writing parquet file in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pyarrow

I have a parquet file with 2 columns A and B. The column A has a data type string and B has a data type float64. The data type of column B need to be changed to int64. Since its not feasible to alter a parquet file, I created a new parquet file with desired data types, ie, A with string and B with int64. I have implemented this successfully in my local machine, now have to replicate the same in AWS lambda. I am facing issue figuring out the last part ie, writing the parquet file to S3.

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import boto3
from io import BytesIO

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    s3_bucket = 'a_bucket'
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    key_name = 'testfolder/testfile.parquet'

    objSh1 = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=s3_bucket, Key=key_name)

    pq_raw = pq.read_table(source=BytesIO(objSh1['Body'].read()))
    df_raw = pq_raw.to_pandas()
    
    sc = pq_raw.schema
    for column, datatype in zip(sc.names, sc.types):
        print(f"{column}, -> {datatype}")
    print(df_raw.dtypes)
    test_pq_raw = pa.Table.from_pandas(
        df=df_raw, 
        preserve_index=False
    )
    sc_test = test_pq_raw.schema
    for column, datatype in zip(sc_test.names, sc_test.types):
        print(f"{column}, -> {datatype}")
        
    schema = {
        'A':pa.string(),
        'B':pa.int64()

    }
    
    fields = [pa.field(x, y) for x, y in schema.items()]
    new_schema = pa.schema(fields)
    
    table = pa.Table.from_pandas(
        df_raw, 
        schema=new_schema, 
        preserve_index=False
    )
```

In my local machine, I can easily write the parquet file with the following line.

```
pq.write_table(table, 'C:\\Users\\username1\\Desktop\\testfolder\\testoutput.parquet')
```

How can I implement the same in AWS lambda function?

Comment: simply write the table to a `/tmp` directory, upload it to s3 using boto3 client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Msvstl for the solution it worked.

```
pq.write_table(table, '/tmp/outputfile.parquet')
with open('/tmp/outputfile.parquet', 'rb') as f:
    s3_client.upload_fileobj(f,s3_bucket,key_output)
```